# plupload UploadProgress

Tags: javascript, jquery, plupload

I was trying to show the uploads progress in percentages inside a div with the id #percentage.
It should work with $('#percentage') , but i could only get it to work by typing the DOM element out all the way in the variable elem.

```
uploader.bind('UploadProgress', function(up, file) {
    var elem = document.getElementById("percentage");
    $("#percentage").innerHTML = "<div>"+ file.percent +"%</div>"; //doesnt work
    elem.innerHTML = "<div>"+ file.percent +"%</div>"; //works
    $('#'+file.id).find('.progress').css('width',file.percent+'%')
});
```

Maybe anyone knows what my error is here?

Edit: it worked by adding [0] to the $("#percentage").

Comment: maybe i need to add [0] like this? $('#percentage')[0]

Comment: The subject of this question is misleading. Really, this is a jQuery question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

have you tried ?

```
$("#percentage").html("<div>"+ file.percent +"%</div>");
```

see : http://api.jquery.com/html/